# How to prevent multiple post with same meta value being created simultaneously in Wordpress (with ajax)

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to make my own appointment system for WordPress. For this, I created a post type called "appointments". When users select a service from the service list, the available dates and times are listed. When the available date and time are selected and the appointment is created, a meta key named "appointment_datetime" is added for this appointment. Here is where the problem started.

**Two different users should not be able to make an appointment for the same service at the same time.** Therefore, when a user tries to create an appointment, the following method is used to check whether the date and time he chose are available.

```
$already_reserved = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'appointments',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'datetime',
            'value' => $date_time, // timestamps
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'services',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $service_id,
        )
    )
));
if ( !empty($already_reserved->posts) ) {
    $response = 'Sorry, this date is full.';
} else {
    // create new appointment post
    // ...
}
```

And here is the ajax code I used:

```
var $response = jQuery('#response');
$('#createnew').click(function () {
    var service = document.getElementById('service').value;
    var datetime = document.getElementById('datetime').value;
    $response.html("<div class='loading'>Waiting...</div>");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: myajax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'new_appoitment',
            service: service,
            datetime: datetime,
            // ... another customer details
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $response.html('');
            $response.append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**After all; When two different users click the button at the same time, they can create an appointment for the same date and time.** Is there any way I can prevent this?

Comment: The likelihood that two users will submit/click at exactly the same time is really small. We're talking milliseconds... What you could do if you wanted to be absolutely certain is create a 'hold' record, a temporary record in the DB that sets a 'date/time' as being held and check that before you allow a user to submit the appointment request.  But then, what if two people are selecting the date/time at the exact same time?  I think what you really need to do is just run a validation that the date/time is not taken before adding to the database.

Comment: Yes, it is really unlikely. However, sometimes I may encounter such a situation during really busy periods. It's actually more than milliseconds. It gives the same result in about 5-6 seconds. @TonyDjukic

Comment: I can see a user getting frustrated booking their time slot and then learning it’s no longer available.  For user experience I’d consider placing a hold on a date/time, so at least that way you don’t have two users booking a time slot.  You could do it using transients.

Comment: Well, can you explain this with a short example? @TonyDjukic

Comment: Not really; there’s far too many things I don’t know about your system/set-up to even begin addressing this.  Are the time slots pre-configured, are they postmeta, are the custom-posts, are they taxonomies, do they even use the WordPress data structure?  Is this a third party plugin being used?  Is it all entirely custom?

Comment: Best I can suggest is a) when a user is choosing their date and time, you use AJAX to check if that date/time combination is taken, but that means if it isn’t, b) you have to record that it’s currently “on hold” because someone else trying to book the same date/time... you want to run these checks using jQuery/AJAX when the user is picking the date and time from your calendar picker.

Answer (score 0):

first of all at the end of using a new WP_Query it's good pratice to always use wp_reset_postdata(); to be sure nothing had compromise your database.

```
$already_reserved = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'appointments',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'datetime',
            'value' => $date_time, // timestamps
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'services',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $service_id,
        )
    )
  wp_reset_postdata();
));
```

and to answer your question, why don't use another if when the button is pressed, right before the appointment is set on the database. like so

```
if ( !empty($already_reserved->posts) ) {
    $response = 'Sorry, this date is full.';
} else {
    // create new appointment post
    // ...
    // the user has everything and click the button
    if ( !empty($already_reserved->posts) ) {
        $response = 'Sorry, this date is no longer available.'; 
    } else {
    // the appointment is set on the database
    }
}
```

this is supposing that first there is a validation of the date and only after that the user / users press the button to confirm.
if the button has a specific function try to edit that function to make this validation before set the appointment on the database.

Comment: Yes, I tried before you post this answer, but it didn't work. I even put a check operation after the whole function was completed but it still didn't work. Different users can add posts at the same time.